# I am making navbar that hides navbar on scrolling over 100px but doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I have this code for making a navbar that hides on scrolling over 100px. but couldn't solve it!!

```
function Nav() {
    const [show, handleShow]= useState(false);
        const transitionNavBar = () => {
        if (window.scrollY > 100){
        handleShow(false);
        } else {
        handleShow(true);
        }
    };
    
       useEffect (() => {
          window.addEventListener("scroll", transitionNavBar)
          return()=>window.removeEventListener("scroll", transitionNavBar)
       }, [])
        
        return (
            <div className={"nav ${show && 'nav_black'}"}>
```

here 'nav' and 'nav_black' are two classes for navbar. This code {"nav ${show && 'nav_black'}"} doesn't work.

Comment: are you actually using double quotes there or is that a typo? `className={"nav ${show && 'nav_black'}"}`. Because you cannot use dynamic variables like `${show}` using double quotes , for that you have to use template literals using backtick(`).

Comment: At first I was using with className={'nav ${show && 'nav_black'}'} at the beginning. The VS code shows an error and replacing that single quote with double no error displayed but still didn't solved. so I used a double quote on posting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div className={"nav ${show && 'nav_black'}"}>` won't work because you are using double quotes instead of a backtick(`)

You cannot use dynamic variables like ${show} using double quotes , for that you have to use template literals using backtick(`).
So please change this line to :

```
<div className={`nav ${show ?'nav_black':''}`}>
```

Also if you write `${show && 'nav_black'}` it will add `undefined` as a class. So change that to `${show ?'nav_black':''}` instead.

Comment: Nice! Here's a Stackblitz with the full solution (I also changed useState('false') to useState('true') so that by default the nav bar would show up:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-s8ig4k?file=src/App.js

Comment: I also changed const [show, handleShow] = useState(true); to const [show, setShow] = useState(true);  It works either way (as long as you change the method references below as well).  But I've only seen up to now examples with the set prefix.  Is "setShow" the appropriate way?  Or are both ok conventions?

Comment: @Luke , thanks for the example. And I think you are ok using it either way.